# Developing a data parser, not sure where to begin?

Tags: c++, asp.net, windows, parsing

I've been asked in work to develop some in-house software for our support team, I haven't done much programming in the last 18 months since I left University and never really dedicated too much of my time then, but now I'm really wanting to dedicate some serious time to it and learn programming properly.  I still remember all the basics from what I was taught.  The language I used the most was Java, although I've spent some time iOS developing in Objective-C.

The program in question appears to be relatively simple, we have .dat files that contain information that we often compare against reports, I've been asked to create a data parser type program where the file is loaded and outputted into human readable format pref in columns, as currently, in it's raw form, it's a long string of numbers and letters.

I've been told that C++ would be a good way forward, although after borrowing a few books from the devlopers, they've told me that doing in a web based language might be better.

I can't really decide which avenue to go down, any input from here on in would be appreciated.

Comment: Since you have the most experience with java, write it in that first.  If you still want to try other languages, I'd take a look at porting it to python, c#, and c++ (whichever tickles your fancy).

Comment: Do you have a spec for the contents of this data file?

Comment: If you are just parsing text, python is the quickest most direct way. Opening a file is one line for example, as oppoesed to the buffer hoop jumping Java requires.

Comment: The format of the data is \A!|PN001209240910381000AG0000000012345

As an example, that's the comms protocol, the instruction, date, time, function, method of entry, card ID.

Ideally, I'd like to load the file, then it space things out neatly into columns and put things like the date and time into readable format rather than just numbers etc.

Comment: Use perl. It is made for this type of work.

Comment: Since the task you specified is one of the simplest programming tasks conceivable, this question basically amounts to "what is your favorite programming language".  This question should be closed.

Comment: C# supports both the desktop and the web if that's an option. You can see some parsing source code I wrote in C# in [this article](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/strings/a-sscanf-replacement-for-net), [this article](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/algorithms/a-c-expression-evaluator), and [this article](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/strings/a-text-parsing-helper-class), to name a few.